# Discard serializing a map entry with a specific key

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I'm having a map that I need to serialize but when I serialize it I get `jackson infinite recursion (stackoverflowerror)`. So, after debugging a while I found the entry that caused this problem but this entry is a list which contains other objects that have some cyclic dependencies.

Let me write a sample code here.

```
Map<String, ?> params = new HashMap();
// Create some list and add objects with cyclic dependencies to it.
List<ContentObject> problematicList = new ArrayList();
//list.addAll(some problematic objects);

params.put("contentsModified", problematicList);
objectmapper.writeValueAsString(params); // here I get jackson infinite recursion (stackoverflowerror)
```

I tried marking the classes of the objects I found in the problematicList using `@JsonIgnoreType` but it didn't work. Is there any way to write some custom serializer to see if a map contains an entry with the name `contentsModified` and if it finds such entry it doesn't serialize the problematic lists?

Answer (score 1):

You should fix the actual bi-directional mapping with problematic classes when serializing. For example if you have classes **ContentObject** & **BackReferringObject** referring to each other you can use `@JsonBackReference` like:

```
public class ContentObject {
    private String name = "contentsModified";
    private BackReferringObject backReferringObject;
}

public class BackReferringObject {
    @JsonBackReference
    private ContentObject contentObject;
}
```

This tells Jackson to not serialize `contentObject` back again.

If this is not possible you can always write some custom serializer. That would make things more complicated. For example, you could have something like this:

```
public class ContentObjectSerializer extends JsonSerializer<ContentObject> {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public void serialize(ContentObject value, JsonGenerator gen, 
                              SerializerProvider serializers)
            throws IOException {
        if (!value.getName().equals("contentsModified")) {
            var sw = new StringWriter();
            objectMapper.writeValue(sw, value);
            gen.writeRawValue(sw.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

and usage:

```
var objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(ContentObject.class, new ContentObjectSerializer());
objectMapper.registerModule(module);
```

The latter configuration is really needed. You cannot for example annotate your `ContentObject` with `@JsonSerialize(using = ContentObjectSerializer.class)` since then the ObjectMapper inside custom serializer would cause another recursive call chain to custom serializer and cause stack overflow again.

*I realize this is not directly applicable to a Map but as an example*